# Converting cURL command to python request with extra parameters

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

I'm trying to convert cURL command to python requests command.

```
curl -k -i -X POST --form 'session.id=abcdef' --form 'ajax=upload' --form 'file=@myproject.zip;type=application/zip' --form 'project=MyProject' url
```

Here is the python code I wrote to convert this:

```
params = {
    "session.id": 'abcdef',
    "ajax": 'upload',
    "project": 'MyProject',
}

filesDict = {'file': ('myproject.zip', 'application/zip')}

response = requests.post(url = url, params=params, files = filesDict, verify=False)
print(response.status_code, response.json())
```

status_code 200 is returned immediately and no error message is being sent. Also, when checked the command didn't execute at all. Tried online converters, but nothing worked.

Am I doing this right? Any help would be really helpful.

Comment: Hi, please follow the guidelines in https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to improve your question. For example, you write that you get a status_code then you say the command didn't execute. Therefore it is very unclear on what exactly is going wrong for you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the thing: `--form` in curl means form-data. It is equavilent to `data` in post request of python, not `params`.